# Difference entre le « cadre » et l'« employé/ouvrier »

Tags: choix-de-mot, professions

Quelle est la différence entre le « cadre » et l'« employé/ouvrier » ? J'ai déjà fait une petite recherche mais je n'arrive pas à comprendre la différence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ces termes sont habituellement employés dans un contexte administratif pour différencier les personnes faisant partie de la direction d'une entreprise (les cadres) et celles qui n'en font pas partie (les employés ou ouvriers).

[Le grand dictionnaire terminologique de l'Office québécois de la langue française](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/) offre les définitions suivantes :

[Cadre](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8350894)

> Personne qui exerce une fonction de direction dans un organisme ou une entreprise, et qui détient des pouvoirs décisionnels.
>   Note : En France, les termes *manageur* et *manageuse* ont été officialisés par la Commission générale de terminologie et de néologie, en 2000.

[Gestionnaire](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26526884) (synonyme)

> Personne qui a la responsabilité du pilotage de l’action collective au sein d’une organisation, assure la bonne marche des fonctions liées à la gestion et met en œuvre tous les moyens humains et matériels disponibles pour atteindre les objectifs préalablement fixés dans le cadre d’un plan déterminé.
>   Note : Le gestionnaire remplit trois rôles complémentaires et interdépendants : un rôle interpersonnel, un rôle informationnel ainsi qu’un rôle décisionnel. Il se consacre à des fonctions de planification, d’organisation, de direction, de mesure et de contrôle.

Le dictionnaire de l'Académie française offre également cette définition :

> 6- Par méton. Personne chargée d'une tâche d'encadrement, de contrôle, de commandement dans une entreprise, un parti, un syndicat. *Cadre supérieur. Cadre moyen. Former des cadres qualifiés.*

Comment: Il est à noter que de nos jours, le côté "encadrement" et "responsabilité" du cadre est très largement perdu. Ce sont devenus des employés comme les autres ou presque. Même les nouveaux employés rentrent en tant que cadre si leur diplôme est assez élevé, en gros (bac +5). C'est en tous cas le cas dans la quasi totalité des sociétés de service.

Comment: Comme cela a déjà été dit, la nuance d'encadrement est largement surannée. Pour différencier _objectivement_ un cadre d'un non-cadre, il faut regarder la caisse de retraite à laquelle le sujet cotise. Après, pour les raisons qui ont poussé l'entreprise à définir un recrutement pour un "cadre" ou un "non cadre", c'est en théorie l'encadrement...

Comment: @LaurentC.  En France, *le cadre technique*,  diplômé scientifique, a des responsabilités sur la réalisation d'un projet. *Le cadre supérieur* (tout aussi diplômé, mais en gestion) a au moins un mandat social (il peut décider du salaire et de la carrière de ses collaborateurs et souvent, il est impliqué dans les décisions de la direction. Le cadre technique peut évoluer en cadre supérieur selon ses capacités de gestion.